# Thermal emission of materials at microwave frequencies

Tags: thermal-radiation

Can anyone suggest a source of information that gives details of the thermal emission spectra (or emissivity) of different materials at RF/microwave frequencies? I'm specifically interested in stainless steel, borosilicate glass and liquid nitrogen at 1.4GHz (21cm). (My searching has only turned up figures at um wavelengths)

Background: I would like to make a cold calibration target for a radiometer. These often appear to consist of a stainless steel dewar (vacuum flask), containing some RF absorbent material, such as polyurethane foam, immersed in liquid nitrogen. I would like to understand the material properties a bit more, to see if a dewar with a borosilicate glass inner could be used instead of just stainless steel and the importance of the foam in the LN2 (I presume the foam has higher emissivity at microwave frequencies, due to it's high absorptivity).

Essentially, I want to be sure the radiometer is looking at something that has a brightness temperature of 77K at 1.4GHz and not less because of low emissivity or higher because of the container.

edit: For conductors, it seems the Hagen–Rubens relation can be used to calculate the emissivity from resistance as described [here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/bulletin/11/nbsbulletinv11n4p607_A2b.pdf)